# I cant add JTextfield to JFrame on top of ImageIcon

Tags: java, swing

This is my code. Sorry for any formatting errors. Anyways, when I create my JTextField and add to the JFrame I only see my image icon, but I dont see the JTextField over it. What am I doing wrong?

```
package com.company;

 import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class Main extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException {

    String path = "C:\\Users\\home\\Pictures\\Papa2.jpg";
    File file = new File(path);
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.getContentPane().add(label);
    f.pack();
    f.setLocation(200, 200);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setResizable(false);

    JTextField text = new JTextField(40);
    text.setVisible(true);
    f.add(text);
}
    }
```

Comment: 1) call `f.setVisible(true)` AFTER you do `f.add(text)`. 2) You don't need the `text.setVisible(true)`. 3) Change the layout manager of the `contentPane` or add `f` to something different than `BorderLayout.CENTER`, otherwise you will only be able to see the textfield the next time.

Comment: Yes to LuxxMiner, and to reinforce:  JFrame uses BorderLayout by default, which only shows one component in the center.  Make a `JPanel`, add both the label and the text field to that, then add just the JPanel to the JFrame.  You'll have to experiment with the layout of the panel to get the position relationship you want.

Comment: @markspace But the OP has changed the `contentPane` of the `JFrame` thereby, changing the layout manager that will be used (which is none as `JLabel` doesn't have a layout manager by default)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm not sure I follow.  Neither the OP nor I said anything about changing the layout manager of the JFrame.  (JPanel, yes, for me.)

Comment: @markspace No sorry I stand corrected, for some reason I thought they were using `setContentPane`

Answer (score 1):

Adding the components to a `JPanel` and then the panel to the frame worked best for me.

like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException {

 String path = "C:\\Users\\home\\Pictures\\Papa2.jpg";
 File file = new File(path);
 BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
 JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
 JFrame f = new JFrame();
 JTextField text = new JTextField(40);
 JPanel panel = new JPanel();
 panel.add(label);
 panel.add(text);
 f.add(panel);
 f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 f.getContentPane().add(label);
 f.pack();
 f.setLocation(200, 200);
 f.setVisible(true);
 f.setResizable(false);
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I only see my image icon, but I dont see the JTextField over it.

If you are trying to make the image a background image with the text field painted on top of the image then you can do something like:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(...) );
label.setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
label.add( textField );

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible( true );
```

This will only work if the text field is smaller than the image.